# jQuery how to fadIn adding a class?

Tags: jquery

When I hover the `#PARENT` `div` this script adds/removes class `highlight` to it. I want to add some grace to it by making this class(color/background-img really) fading, and here i fail, but why?

Fiddle for yours comfort: http://jsfiddle.net/4y4vQ/1/

```
<div id=PARENT>
    <div id=CHILD>Content</div>
</div>​
<script>
$("#PARENT").hover(function () {
    $(this).fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $("#PARENT").toggleClass("highlight");
    });
});​
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jQuery UI Switch Class, This one will do exactly what you need

http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS3 transitions like so:

```
#PARENT{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s ease;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
  }
#PARENT:hover {
  background: red;
  }
```

This will also not require a lot of processing by the client.

Comment: IE doesn't matter at this point. If we don't create our pages for the future then IE will live on.

Answer (score 0):

`fadeIn` doesn't work like that. It changes the opacity of an element from 0 to 1. Since you element is already visible, it does nothing. You toggleClass is in the callback, so it gets called as soon as the animation is finished, which is immediately.

You'll need to use a custom animation with `.animate`.